# Adding a full revolution (360 degrees) to Directional Rotation in TweenMax

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

I am creating a carousel and I am using GSAP's TweenMax and its Directional Rotation plug-in to spin the carousel.

The carousel spins slowly until the user clicks the "Get Started" button which then spins the carousel to its first element.  My problem is that I want to add a full rotation to the element, but even when I add 360 degrees to the spin target, it doesn't rotate. I figure that degrees act more like coordinates rather than distances.

This is what the code originally was to spin to the target element:

```
TweenMax.to( carousel, 1, { directionalRotation:{ rotationY: Math.degrees( item.eq( 0 ).angle + Math.PI / 2 ) + "_cw" }, ease: Expo.easeInOut, onComplete: stopUpdateAppearance });
```

This is what I thought would do the trick (notice the 360):

```
TweenMax.to( carousel, 1, { directionalRotation:{ rotationY: Math.degrees( item.eq( 0 ).angle + Math.PI / 2 ) + 360 + "_cw" }, ease: Expo.easeInOut, onComplete: stopUpdateAppearance });
```

But this didn't work.  So then I tried:

```
TweenMax.to( carousel, 1, { directionalRotation:{ rotationY: "+=360_cw" }, ease: Expo.easeInOut });
TweenMax.to( carousel, 1, { directionalRotation:{ rotationY: Math.degrees( item.eq( 0 ).angle + Math.PI / 2 ) + "_cw" }, ease: Expo.easeInOut, onComplete: stopUpdateAppearance });
```

This had the same result of just spinning to the start position.

I'm not too familiar with GSAP and TweenMax that I can't tell if it's my syntax or my approach.  What do you think?

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle or codepen example so we can see your code in context. So we can see what `item.eq( 0 ).angle` and `Math.degrees( item.eq( 0 ).angle + Math.PI / 2` outputs out in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try subtracting the current carousel rotation (at the time the button is clicked) from 360.

For example

```
var currentRotation = 50;
TweenMax.to( carousel, 1, { directionalRotation:{rotationY:"+=" + (360-currentRotation) + "_cw"}, ease: Expo.easeInOut });
```

P.S. Just guessing:

If you dont want specifically to rotate around Y axis, maybe you should remove the rotational object {rotationY} and use this instead:

```
TweenMax.to( carousel, 1, { directionalRotation:"+=" + (360-currentRotation) + "_cw", ease: Expo.easeInOut });
```

Hope this helps